# Get URL parameters with if not null condition in laravel 7 blade

Tags: php, laravel, view, laravel-blade, laravel-7

```
{{ Request::get('utm_source') }}
```

I am using this method to get the parameters from URL in Laravel 7 blade. How to add a **IF NOT NULL** so that if the URL parameters are empty we have to declare a value instead of request URL.

Comment: not getting exact your issue by if the url parameters are empty

Comment: you can refer link for the optional parameters in routing.
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#parameters-optional-parameters

Answer (score 0):

To make sure, `null` isn't outputted in the blade template if the value is null, you can do the following:

```php
{{ Request::get('utm_source') ?? 'default value' }}
```